# Find character with most occurrences in string?

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I have a string:

```
"abbbbccd"
```

`b` has the most occurrences. When using C++, the easiest way to handle this is inserting each character into a `map<>`. Do I have to do the same thing in C#? Is there an elegant way to do it using LINQ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key
```

Notes:

- if you need this to work on ancient (2.0) versions of .Net consider [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx). If you can't use C# 3.0 (targeting .Net 2.0) you probably better off with other solutions due to missing lambda support. Another .Net 2.0+ option is covered in [xanatos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069918/477420).
- for the case of `"aaaabbbb"` only one of those will be returned (thanks  [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) for comment).  If you need all of the elements with maximum count, use [Albin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069735/477420) instead.
- due to sorting this if O(n log n) solution. If you need better than that - find Max value by linear search instead of sorting first which will give O(n). See [LINQ: How to perform .Max() on a property of all objects in a collection and return the object with maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret)

Comment: Note that .NET Core now has a [microoptimization](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.SpeedOpt.cs,166) for `OrderBy(...).First()`, so this is now O(n) not O(n log n)

Answer (score 11):

This because someone asked for a 2.0 version, so no LINQ.

```
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

int max = 0;

foreach (char c in "abbbbccccd")
{
    int i;
    dict.TryGetValue(c, out i);
    i++;
    if (i > max)
    {
        max = i;
    }
    dict[c] = i;
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> chars in dict)
{
    if (chars.Value == max)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", chars.Key, chars.Value);
    }
}
```

Instead this for the LINQ version. It will extract paired "bests" (aaaabbbb == a, b). It WON'T work if str == String.Empty.

```
var str = "abbbbccccd";

var res = str.GroupBy(p => p).Select(p => new { Count = p.Count(), Char = p.Key }).GroupBy(p => p.Count, p => p.Char).OrderByDescending(p => p.Key).First();

foreach (var r in res) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", res.Key, r);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string testString = "abbbbccd";
var charGroups = (from c in testString
                    group c by c into g
                    select new
                    {
                        c = g.Key,
                        count = g.Count(),
                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.count);
foreach (var group in charGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.c + ": " + group.count);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired from Stephen's answer, almost the same:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var dict = input.ToLookup(x => x);
    if (dict.Count == 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    var maxCount = dict.Max(x => x.Count());
    return dict.Where(x => x.Count() == maxCount).Select(x => x.Key);
}

var modes = "".Mode().ToArray(); //returns { }
var modes = "abc".Mode().ToArray(); //returns { a, b, c }
var modes = "aabc".Mode().ToArray(); //returns { a }
var modes = "aabbc".Mode().ToArray(); //returns { a, b }
```

**Update:** Did a quick benchmarking of this answer vs [Jodrell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16817294/661933) answer (release build, debugger detached, oh yes)

> source = "";
>
> iterations = 1000000
>
> result:

```
this - 280 ms
Jodrell's - 900 ms
```

> source = "aabc";
>
> iterations = 1000000
>
> result:

```
this - 1800 ms
Jodrell's - 3200 ms
```

> source = fairly large string - 3500+ char
>
> iterations = 10000
>
> result:

```
this - 3200 ms
Jodrell's - 3000 ms
```

Comment: I'm almost interested enough to do a peformance comparison. There's probably not much in it.

Comment: @Jodrell post it if you do. I will try from my side too.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 3**

Here is my last answer which I think (just) shades Nawfal's for performance on longer sequences.

However, given the reduced complexity of [Nawfal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16818909/659190), and its more universal performance, especially in relation to the question, I'd choose that.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mode<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var counts = source.GroupBy(t => t, comparer)
        .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .ToList();

    if (counts.Count == 0)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    var maxes = new List<int>(5);
    int maxCount = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < counts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (counts[i].Count < maxCount)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (counts[i].Count > maxCount)
        {
            maxes.Clear();
            maxCount = counts[i].Count;
        }

        maxes.Add(i);
    }

    return maxes.Select(i => counts[i].Key);
}
```

---

<s>**EDIT 2**</s>

---

<s>**EDIT**</s>

---

---

If you want an efficient generic solution, that accounts for the fact that multiple items could have the same frequency, start with this extension,

```
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<T>>>Frequency<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    return source.GroupBy(t => t, comparer)
        .GroupBy(
            g => g.Count(),
            (k, s) => new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<T>>(
                k,
                s.Select(g => g.First())))
        .OrderByDescending(f => f.Key);
}
```

This extension works in all of the following scenarios

```
var mostFrequent = string.Empty.Frequency().FirstOrDefault();

var mostFrequent = "abbbbccd".Frequency().First();
```

or,

```
var mostFrequent = "aaacbbbcdddceee".Frequency().First();
```

Note that `mostFrequent` is a `KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<char>>`.

---

If so minded you could simplify this to another extension,

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Mode<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var mode = source.GroupBy(
            t => t,
            (t, s) => new { Value = t, Count = s.Count() }, comparer)
        .GroupBy(f => f.Count)
        .OrderbyDescending(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

    return mode == null ? Enumerable.Empty<T>() : mode.Select(g => g.Value);
}
```

which obviously could be used thus,

```
var mostFrequent = string.Empty.Mode();

var mostFrequent = "abbbbccd".Mode();

var mostFrequent = "aaacbbbcdddceee".Mode();
```

here, `mostFrequent` is an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Nice solution. I think its the same as xanatos's second answer but with an extra check for empty collection check, which is good. Btw, the most occurrent thing is called mode, not median.

Comment: @nawfal, I'm wondering why I made such a stupid error. Anyway, its essentially the same as Albin's answer too, empty check and generisiscm aside. What I don't understand is why the popular but inferior answer keeps getting the votes.

Comment: Jodrell, simple, its the shortest and sweetest for most at first sight. Or may be thats the functionality they wanted ;)

Comment: +1 for the benchmarking :) [Here is another alternative from David B](http://stackoverflow.com/a/356453/661933)

Comment: Jodrell, how is your method in (edit 2) able to finish off something in 3 ms when others take much longer time. I suspect something wrong there. Did you forget to execute the query?

Comment: Could you remove that benchmark or correct it? 3 ms is highly misleading.

Comment: @nawfal, its not but, the because of the simplicity of the benchmark not using the return value, the compiler skipped the execution.

Comment: Yes, so is it appropriate to be there? Other than that, I think something is wrong with your last edit. What is `maxCount` initialized to? You're nowhere assigning it something too..

Comment: @nawfal, all fixed I hope. Although I may have orphaned part of your post.

Comment: Jodrell, I took my +1 off, I find something incredibly smelly there under the `for` loop. Try for "aaabbbccc"

Comment: @nawfal, fixed it. I have to transcribe my code to get it up here and its prone to my very human errors.

Answer (score 1):

Find the simplest and without built in function used

sample code and links

```
public char MostOccurringCharInString(string charString)
{
int mostOccurrence = -1;
char mostOccurringChar = ' ';
foreach (char currentChar  in charString)
{
    int foundCharOccreence = 0;
    foreach (char charToBeMatch in charString)
    {
        if (currentChar == charToBeMatch)
            foundCharOccreence++;
    }
    if (mostOccurrence < foundCharOccreence)
    {
        mostOccurrence = foundCharOccreence;
        mostOccurringChar = currentChar;
    }
 }
  return mostOccurringChar;
}
```

Know more about how to get max occurrence and what is the flow.

[How to get max occurred character and max occurrence  in string](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/get-max-occurred-character-in-string.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#simplified expression using LINQ#
string text = "abccdeeef";
int length = text.ToCharArray().GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => 
x.Count()).First().Count();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for posting an answer! Generally, answers which are just code without any explanation get removed/downvoted. I'd suggest adding some explanation to your code, so that future viewers can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to solve the problem.

1. Linq
2. Dictionary
3. Using system.

You can choose based on your preferences. Listing one of it.

```
  private static void CalculateMaxCharCountUsingArray(string actualString)
        {
            char[] charArray = actualString.ToCharArray();

            int[] arr = new int[256];
            int maxCount = 0;
            char maxChar = ' ';
            foreach (var r in charArray)
            {
                arr[r] = arr[r] + 1;
                if (maxCount < arr[r])
                {
                    maxCount = arr[r];
                    maxChar = r;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("This character " + maxChar + " that appeared maximum times : " + maxCount);

            IEnumerable<char> distinctCharArray = charArray.Distinct();

            foreach(var r in distinctCharArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This character " + r + " that appeared  times " + arr[r]  + " in a string");

            }
        }
```

I learned all of them from the below [link](https://youtu.be/ZHuAE1QwIeE) for your reference.

Comment: Only 256 characters? Try unicode. Also, the question is how to do it in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This is Femaref's solution modified to return multiple letters if their Count matches. Its no longer a one-liner but still reasonably concise and should be fairly performant.

```
    public static IEnumerable<char> GetMostFrequentCharacters(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return Enumerable.Empty<char>();

        var groups = str.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Letter = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();
        var max = groups.Max(g2 => g2.Count);
        return groups.Where(g => g.Count == max).Select(g => g.Letter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
class CharCount
{
    public void CountCharacter()
    {
        int n;
        Console.WriteLine("enter the no. of elements: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        char[] chararr = new char[n];
        Console.WriteLine("enter the elements in array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            chararr[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Dictionary<char, int> count = chararr.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

        foreach(KeyValuePair<char, int> key in count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Occurrence of {0}: {1}",key.Key,key.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code shows frequencies of each letter, not max one as asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //find most occuring character and count from below string

        string totest = "abcda12Zernn111y";

        string maxOccuringCharacter = "";
        int maxOccurence = 0;string currentLoopCharacter = ""; string updatedStringToTest = "";int cnt = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < totest.Length; i++)
        {
            currentLoopCharacter = totest[i].ToString();
            updatedStringToTest = totest.Replace(currentLoopCharacter, "");

            cnt = totest.Length - updatedStringToTest.Length;

            if (cnt > maxOccurence)
            {
                maxOccuringCharacter = currentLoopCharacter;
                maxOccurence = cnt;
            }

            totest = updatedStringToTest;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The most occuring character is {0} and occurence was {1}", maxOccuringCharacter, maxOccurence.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using LINQ and a Dictionary data structure as a lookup list:

```
        var str = "abbbbccd";
        var chrArr = str.ToCharArray();
        Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        foreach (char a in chrArr)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(a))
                dic[a]++;
            else
                dic.Add(a, 1);
        }
        int count = dic.Values.Max();
        char val = dic.Where(d => d.Value == count).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```