# How to check if string contains single occurence of substring?

Tags: c#, string

I have this:

```
string strings = "a b c d d e";
```

And I need something similar to `string.Contains()`, but I need to know not only **whether a string is present**(in case above a letter), but also **if it is present only ONE SINGLE time**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why not use a simple Linq statement to return the character that occurs the most you can use a `GroupBy` and `OrderDescending`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the most occurrence of a character in string C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069687/find-the-most-occurrence-of-a-character-in-string-c)

Comment: I don't think that is a dupe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `LastIndexOf(String)` and `IndexOf(String)` and verify that the values returned are equal. Of course also check if the String is found at all(i.e the returned value is not -1).

Comment: Actually, the latter is just `IndexOf(String)`, no "First".

Answer (score 7):

You could use LINQ

```
int count = strings.Count(f => f == 'd');
```

Comment: -1 Andrew this is good but the condition should not be hard coded

Comment: This only works for characters though. He mentioned he wanted to find an entire string within the original string.

Comment: Bit Destroyer - True, I missed that

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

```
if(Regex.Matches(input,Regex.Escape(pattern)).Count==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple alternative:

```
if(strings.Split(new [] { "a" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below... it will help you...

```
string strings = "a b c d d e";
string text ="a";
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
while ((i = strings.IndexOf(text, i)) != -1)
{
    i += text.Length;
    count++;
}
if(count == 0)
Console.WriteLine("String not Present");

if(count == 1)
Console.WriteLine("String Occured Only one time");

if(Count>1)
Console.WriteLine("String Occurance : " + count.Tostring());
```

Comment: You seem to confuse your `strings` and `text` variables. For example when you say `text.IndexOf(text, i)`. Note that it might be interesting to know if the search string existed as two substrings which overlapped. Like if we searched for substring `"reassure"` inside `"XXXXXreassureassureXX"`, one could want to count two matches (not clear in the question). So watch how much you increment `i`. Also watch the increment of `i` because if you get out of the bounds of the `strings` variable, the next `IndexOf` will throw an exception, not just return `-1`.

Comment: First try your own code with `strings = "a b c d d e"` and `text = "e"`. After you fixed that problem, try you code with `strings = "XXXXXreassureassureXX"` and `text = "reassure"`. What answer do you prefer in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
    string source = "a b c d d e";
    string search = "d";
    int i = source.IndexOf(search, 0);
    int j = source.IndexOf(search, i + search.Length);
    if (i == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("No match");
    else if (j == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("One match");   
    else
        Console.WriteLine("More match");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length (minus 1) of the array myString.Split('a') assuming that you're searching for the occurrences of 'a'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [StringUtils.countMatches](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches-java.lang.CharSequence-char-)