# Check if string contains substring more than once

Tags: c#, search

To search for a substring inside a string I can use the `contains()` function.
But how can I check if a string contains a substring more than once?

To optimize that: For me it is sufficient to know that there is more than one result not how many.

Comment: I would loop through the string and remove everything from the first occurrence back, then update a counter and loop again. But there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: Strongly related: [How to check if string contains single occurence of substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775357). One answer suggests checking if `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` agree.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to take advantage of fast `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` string methods. Use next code snippet. Idea is to check if first and last indexes are different and if first index is not -1, which means string is present.

```
string s = "tytyt";

var firstIndex = s.IndexOf("tyt");

var result = firstIndex != s.LastIndexOf("tyt") && firstIndex != -1;
```

Comment: I like this. Doesn't give you a count but does tell you that contains is plural.

Comment: @Lloyd if you want to search the `count` - it will be much slower algorithm.

Comment: Good example `"tytyt"` because it shows that overlapping of the two substring occurences is a possibility. Checking for two non-overlapping substring occurences is something else.

Comment: It is better to arrange `(a && b && ...)` in order of complexity, I believe `firstIndex != -1` first will make it short-circuit when false and some `LastIndexOf()` calls could potentially be saved.

Answer (score 7):

One line of code with RegEx:

```
return Regex.Matches(myString, "test").Count > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following extension method which uses [`string.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public static bool ContainsMoreThan(this string text, int count, string value,  StringComparison comparison)
{
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return text != "";

    int contains = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while ((index = text.IndexOf(value, index, text.Length - index, comparison)) != -1)
    {
        if (++contains > count)
            return true;
        index++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use it in the following way:

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo porro homero dolorem eu, facilisi inciderint ius in.";
bool containsMoreThanOnce = text.ContainsMoreThan(1, "dolor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // true
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/GOxf9F)

It's a string extension and enables to pass the `count`, the `value` you search and the `StringComparison`(for example to search case-insensitively).

Comment: You may need to use `index + 1` to avoid finding the same substring occurence twice.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: But i'm using `index + 1` already (ok, my first version did not)

Comment: Yeah, didn't see your edit when I commented. Maybe if `toSearch` had only `Length` one, and the first (and only) occurence of it were at the very end of `text`, then your last call to `IndexOf` would throw an exception.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: No, it was exception free imho. However, now i've made it an extension and improved it in several ways.

Comment: It's cool now (upvoted). I thought if you searched for a length-1 string and it was found in the very end, it would fail, but I tried it out, and it only fails with the empty string. With your new code, the call `"Hello".ContainsMoreThan(100, "", StringComparison.Ordinal);` throws a "bad" exception. Yes, it's pretty meaningles to search for the empty string, of course, but it could happen if you didn't know that the string was empty.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I've added an `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))` check which should prevent it. Are you working in the quality management department? ;-)

Comment: Nah, not really. I saw some other code where they added `value.Length` to `index` (like `index += value.Length`) instead of just incrementing `index` (they didn't want overlapping substrings), so in that case they could get past the right end of the string `text`. Now, in your code above, if you change your `break;` into an immediate `return false;`, it may be a little more beautiful because then the `return true;` can be moved to outside of the loop. I think.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I think i've found the most concise version, now even the while-expression is useful ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the Regex class. [msdn regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

```
   int count;
   Regex regex = new Regex("your search pattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("your string");
   count = matches.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private bool MoreThanOnce(string full, string part)
{
   var first = full.IndexOf(part);
   return first!=-1 && first != full.LastIndexOf(part);
}
```