# Find the most occurrence of a character in string C#, returning the string of the longest set of recurring characters

Tags: c#, linq

I have an extension to a question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069687/find-the-most-occurrence-of-a-character-in-string-c)

However I want to return the list of the longest set of reaccuring characters in the original string, not a list of char & their relative count, ordered by higheest.

I was fairly well versed in link, but had never come accross an instance of querying char types in a string and thought someone could give me a hint to help me understand specific use-cases of LINQ...

Thanks

Comment: ie.  for "abbbbccd" return "bbbb"

Comment: can you provide an example. it would be helpful to understand the question better.

Comment: if the input is "abbbbccdb" - do you expect the output to be "bbbb" or "bbbbb"?

Comment: bbbb should be returned

Comment: Also "aaabbbbaabbcccddccaabb" would return "bbbb" not "bbbbbbbb"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the longest substring. For example, for `aabccc` you want

I also assume the problem domain is strings of Unicode characters. Unfortunately, .NET's `System.String` is a sequence of codeunits. To count or index Unicode characters, you have to deal with them as codepoints. The easiest way to do that is to change the encoding to UTF-32 since there is then one `int` per codepoint, and a codepoint is a numeric identifier for a Unicode character [generally speaking].

After that, to find the longest subsequence of identical characters, you have to run through the whole sequence. Run-length encoding is a generalized method that I'm using as an intermediate step. After finding the codepoint and length for the longest subsequence, I recreate a string of them.

```
        const string test = "aabccc"; // contains barber pole characters
        Console.WriteLine(test);

        var longest = test.ToCodepoints().RunLengthEncode().OrderByDescending(itemCount => itemCount.Item2).First();
        var subsequence = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(longest.Item1), longest.Item2));
        Console.WriteLine(subsequence);
```

Converting a string to codepoints is equivalent to converting to UTF-32. It can be done with a `System.Text.Encoding` method but then you end up with an array of bytes that then must be converted to codepoints. Here is an IEnumerable that yields a sequence of `int`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> ToCodepoints(this String s)
    {
        var codeunits = s.ToCharArray();
        var i = 0;

        while (i < codeunits.Length)
        {
            int codepoint;
            if (Char.IsSurrogate(codeunits[i]))
            {
                codepoint = Char.ConvertToUtf32(codeunits[i], codeunits[i + 1]);
                i += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                codepoint = codeunits[i];
                i += 1;
            }
            yield return codepoint;
        }

    }
```

Run-length encoding produces a Tuple of the codepoint (`Item1`) and the length of the run (`Item2`) for each subsequence of identical codepoints:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, int>> RunLengthEncode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        T item = default(T); // value never used
        int length = 0;
        foreach (var nextItem in sequence)
        {
            if (length == 0) // first item
            {
                item = nextItem;
                length = 1;
            }
            else if (item.Equals(nextItem)) // continuing run
            {
                length++;
            }
            else // run boundary
            {
                var run = Tuple.Create(item, length);
                item = nextItem;
                length = 1;
                yield return run;
            }
        }
        if (length > 0) // last run
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(item, length);
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'barber pole characters', googling just brings up the spiral columns you see outside barber shops.  I assume you might mean the pipe character ||, however pasting your first bit of code into a console app brings little squares with a question mark inside.   Please clarify.  thanks.  I will work the rest of your example.

Comment: Unicode Character '[BARBER POLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f488/index.htm)' (U+1F488) is simply an example of a character that is represented by two System.Char elements. See (The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets)[http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html] by Joel Spolsky. Visual Studio and StackOverflow on (IE) should display that character fine. Other browsers/systems/fonts might fall back to a box with hex digits in it. But cmd.exe sees it as two chars that it doesn't know so it shows ??

Comment: ok thanks for that...except it returned a 404 because of your square bracket, so the updated link is http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  Your example has opened up alot of new territory for me.  I did find a reference on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_pole#Computer_science in relation to the CHARGEN service.  What will I miss using the default UTF16 encoding because it also uses codepoints?  I see that many languages are supported already in Utf32

Comment: After testing with some very large strings, this is the correct answer, as it seems the others would concatenate any other characters which were the same but not as the longest but appears in the string in a shorter repetition.  ie "aabbbaabbccdd" would return "bbbbb", not "bbb" which is the longest repeated character group in the list

Answer (score 4):

Using the linked example:

```
var largest = input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First();
var asString = new string(largest.Key, largest.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks this is clean, quick and concise.  As a web developer, not system programmer, it is much more helpful for me to have easy to use syntax as I have to keep up to date with alot of client-side tech and styling issues.  I see where I was tripping up now, I actually had the first statement, but was not sure how to take the result and feed it into a new string as you do in your 2nd statement.

Comment: I should have specified a more specific example, I wish there was a nice brief expression to do this

Comment: Note that @magister wanted the longest recurring string, e.g. "aabbbaa" -> "bbb" not "aaaa".

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create lots of intermediate objects. You just need to keep track of the character in the longest sequence and the length of that sequence:

```
char longest = '\0';
int longestLength = 0;

char last = '\0';
int lastLength = 0;

foreach (char c in input)
{
    if (c == last)
    {
        lastLength++;

        if (lastLength > longestLength)
        {
            longestLength = lastLength;
            longest = c;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lastLength = 1;
    }

    last = c;
}

var result = new string(longest, longestLength);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't take into account character encoding. Try this: string input = "aabccc"; // contains barber pole characters

Comment: @XavierDecoster This approach works fine for Unicode characters up to 16 bits. For example `string input = "aab\u2764\u2764\u2764\u2605";` is aab❤❤❤★ and correctly results in ❤❤❤. However, the [barber pole character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f488/index.htm) is above the threshold for a 16-bit char and so requires a surrogate pair of chars to encode it. You could tweak this approach to store up to two characters at each stage, and use [`Char.IsSurrogate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xe6etk(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect the surrogates.