# Find Most Frequent Words using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to find most frequent words from a list of strings. I have tried something like [Find the most occurring number in a List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355945/find-the-most-occurring-number-in-a-listint)

but issue is that it returns only one word, but **all those words are required which are most frequent**.

For example, if we call that LINQ query on following list:

```
Dubai
Karachi
Lahore
Madrid
Dubai
Sydney
Sharjah
Lahore
Cairo
```

it should result us in:

ans: Dubai, Lahore

Comment: where is the code that you have written to attempt to solve hte problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a group by and then order by count:

```
var result = list
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Just an unrelated question. Can we apply restriction of selecting only those which exist more than once?

Answer (score 2):

If you need all words which are occurring repeatedly ..

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("B");
            var most = (from i in list
                        group i by i into grp
                        orderby grp.Count() descending
                        select new { grp.Key, Cnt = grp.Count() }).Where (r=>r.Cnt>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get several most frequent words, you can use this method:

```
public List<string> GetMostFrequentWords(List<string> list)
{
    var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
    if (!groups.Any()) return new List<string>();

    var maxCount = groups.First().Count;

    return groups.Where(x => x.Count == maxCount).Select(x => x.word).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var list = @"Dubai,Karachi,Lahore,Madrid,Dubai,Sydney,Sharjah,Lahore,Cairo".Split(',').ToList();
    var result = GetMostFrequentWords(list);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("Dubai", result[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Lahore", result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want `Dubai, Lahore` *only* (i.e. only words with top occurrence, which is 2 in the sample):

```
  List<String> list = new List<String>() {
   "Dubai", "Karachi", "Lahore", "Madrid", "Dubai", "Sydney", "Sharjah", "Lahore", "Cairo"
   };

  int count = -1;

  var result = list
    .GroupBy(s => s, s => 1)
    .Select(chunk => new {
      name = chunk.Key,
      count = chunk.Count()
     })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.count)
    .ThenBy(item => item.name)
    .Where(item => {
      if (count < 0) {
        count = item.count; // side effects, alas (we don't know count a-priory)

        return true;
      }
      else
        return item.count == count;
    })
    .Select(item => item.name);
```

Test:

```
  // ans: Dubai, Lahore
  Console.Write("ans: " + String.Join(", ", result));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there must be better way, but one thing I manage to make (which may help you to make it more optimised) is something like follow

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Dubai");
        list.Add("Sarjah");
        list.Add("Dubai");
        list.Add("Lahor");
        list.Add("Dubai");
        list.Add("Sarjah");
        list.Add("Sarjah");


        int most = list.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
            .Select(grp => grp.Count()).First();
        IEnumerable<string> mostVal = list.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() >= most)
            .Select(grp => grp.Key) ;
```

this will list of those who are occurring most frequent, if two entries are occurring frequency is same, they both will be included.

**NOTE we are not selecting entries having frequency more than once.**