# Find max object field value in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass{
    string field1, field2;
}
```

And I have `List<MyClass>` thats contains the following:

```
list.Add(new MyClass("1","1"));
list.Add(new MyClass("1","2"));
list.Add(new MyClass("1","3"));
list.Add(new MyClass("2","2"));
list.Add(new MyClass("3","2"));
```

I want to find the most frequent value of `field1`, this case I have three times the value "1", one time the value "2" and one time the value "3", How can I get the maximum count value of `field1` (this case is "1")?

Comment: You can use group by

Comment: So you want to find max value or count?

Comment: @Reniuz, Not sure but I think OP want maximum occurrence of value `field1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355945/find-the-most-occurring-number-in-a-listint bun instead of an int youhave an Item.Field

Comment: What if all elment have the same number of occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one field1 value which would have max occurrences ( as in example in OP), a simple GroupBy followed by OrderByDescending would help you.

```
var maxOccuranceItem = list.GroupBy(x => x.field1)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                          .First().Key;
```

Output

```
1
```

But,if there are two set of field1, which has same number of occurrences (in case of tie), I would use following

Scenario

```
list.Add(new MyClass("1","2"));
list.Add(new MyClass("1","3"));
list.Add(new MyClass("2","2"));
list.Add(new MyClass("2","2"));
list.Add(new MyClass("3","2"));
```

Solution for multiple items having max occurrences.

```
var grouped = list.ToLookup(x => x.field1);
var maxOccuranceCount = grouped.Max(x => x.Count());
var maxOccuranceItems = grouped.Where(x => x.Count() == maxOccuranceCount)
                              .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Output

```
1 
2
```

In either case,as others have mentioned, the property needs to be public.

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ for this.

```
string result = list.GroupBy(entry => entry.field1)
    .Max(item => item.Count());
```

But you have to make at least `field1` public because you can not access it otherwise.

And your class `MyClass` does not have a constructor to create instances like you do it in your sample code ;)

If there are more then one element with the same number of entries you have to use something like this.

```
int maxCount = list.GroupBy(entry => entry.Field1)
    .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Count())
    .First()
    .Count();

List<string> result = list.GroupBy(entry => entry.Field1)
    .Where(item => item.Count() == maxCount)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

I splitted the statement because I think it's better to understand and easier to read.

Have a look at [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for more information.